# How to make gradle build use jdk 1.6 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a gradle project imported in IntelliJ IDEA, which is running with jdk 1.8. JAVA_HOME also configured with jdk 1.8. while this project specifically need gradle build run with jdk 1.6, anyone know any extra configuration needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JVM used to run Gradle builds in IntelliJ IDEA can be changed here:

[image: Gradle JVM]

Comment: Would those configured be used only if you select use Local Gradle distribution?

Comment: @user3096841 no