# I am trying to change the IDE for IntelliJ, but It keeps running the wrong version

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a class on Software Engineering and we have a gradle project for a sales system. It requires java 8 to operate, which I have installed on my computer. I also have java 9, which I use for anything else besides that class.

I have a very tedious problem that I can't seem to fix: I can't seem to get intelliJ to use java 8.

I've tried the following things:

**File - Project structure**

Under "Project" - Java 8

Under "Modules" - Everything is set to use Project SDK (1.8)

Under "SDKs" - I only have "1.8" there

**Ctrl + Shift + A -> "Switch IDE boot JDK..."**

I have 3 options there:

1. 1.8.0_152 java (b16) [boot]
2. 1.8.0_152 openjdk (release-1024-b11)[bundled]
3. 1.8.0_181 java (b13)

I've tried all of those but still nothing.

When I open up the project, it says

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java...
```

In the "Run" Tab down below. However, when I type

```
java -version
```

Into the "Terminal" tab, it says

```
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

When I try to execute any **gradlew** command, for example **hsql** or **run**

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.
```

I've tried running our main gradle.build file and not running it before trying those commands, but it doesn't make a difference. Our build.gradle file, if it helps anything:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

version = '1.0'

dependencies {
    compile project(':')
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.6.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.6.2'
}

mainClassName = 'ee.ut.math.tvt.salessystem.ui.SalesSystemUI'

jar {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            if (!configurations.runtime.isEmpty()) {
                attributes('Class-Path': configurations.runtime.collect{it.toURI().toString()}.join(' '))
            }
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

My other team member doesn't seem to have a problem and can run it nicely. Any help will be REALLY appreciated.

Comment: I don't think changing the IntelliJ Java Project version is going to change your terminal version. Run a program and print `System.getProperty("java.version")`, what does it say?

Comment: If running through Intellij, check your settings in `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` to make sure Gradle is using the correct JDK. If running through the terminal you can change the used JDK with `-Dorg.gradle.java.home=<path>`.

Comment: @FrznFlms It prints out 9.0.4

Comment: @Slaw I checked under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and I am using the correct version.

Comment: If worst comes to worst, you could try uninstalling Java 9 and running your program. If any settings were set to use Java 9, they will either switch to Java 8 or IntelliJ will ask you to change them. Once you got that working, you could reinstall Java 9 and cross your fingers IntelliJ doesn't change it back for you.

Answer (score 1):

I thik you have to specify Gradle to use the JVM you want.

Go to settings **->** Build, Execution, Deployment **->** Gradle-> Gradle JVM  and choose the JDK you want. (It's pointed in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43624456/2799066 )

AFAIK giving JVM and command line arguments can also be configurable when importing project to idea.

Comment: I checked under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and I am using the correct version.

Comment: Ok, then I think it may be issue with your JAVA_HOME environment variable. Check if it's pointing your 9.0.4 installation.

Comment: I didn't even have a JAVA_HOME environment variable before so I looked it up, craeted it, and restarted my computer. Now it's set to jdk1.8.0_181, however terminal's java -version is still giving me 9.0.4 as the answer.

Comment: The terminal window in IntelliJ IDEA is independent of any IDE setting. The `java` command does not look at the JAVA_HOME environment variable; instead, the command shell simply runs the first `java` executable that is found in the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working.

I clicked File -> New -> Project from existing sources -> Picked the Project folder and that I wish to overwrite it

Then I set up the initial gradle settings that open up when starting a brand new gradle project and voila, terminal now understands gradlew commands.

It's weird, however, that java -version still shows 9.0.4, but well at least everything seems to work now.

**Tl;Dr for fix: Create a New project from existing sources and overwrite the current project. Pick the correct java version when asked during the setup.**

Comment: `java -version` has nothing to do with IntelliJ. It's like typing into the command prompt. You weren't changing your system default jdk, just your JDK that compiles and runs your project.